# Spring Data Elasticsearch Class Cast exception on Named Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm getting the following exception when trying to use a named query with Spring Data Elasticsearch.

```
ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.aggregation.impl.AggregatedPageImpl cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchPage
```

The query I'm trying to make is:

```
public interface PlayerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<PlayerEntity, String> {
  
  @Query("{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"terms\":{\"playerNumber.keyword\": ?0}}]}}")
  SearchPage<PlayerEntity> fetchPlayers(JSONArray playerNumbers, Pageable pageable);
}
```

If I do not use the `@Query` annotation and instead let Spring derive the query from the method name like so:

```
SearchPage<PlayerEntity> findPlayerEntityByPlayerNumberIn(List<String> playerNumbers, Pageable pageable);
```

It works as expected.  However, the `PlayerNumber` field is a `@MultiField` that supports the the field types of `Text` and `Keyword` like so:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@playersIndexName}")
public class PlayerEntity {

  @MultiField(
      mainField = @Field(type = Text, name = "playerNumber"),
      otherFields = {@InnerField(suffix = "keyword", type = Keyword)})
  private String playerNumber;

  ...
}
```

And I need to use the keyword mapping here for the query and not the text mapping.  As far as I can tell, Spring Data Elasticsearch cannot derive queries from method names on `InnerField`, which is why I went with the named query approach.  But it seems like the using the declared query approach, detailed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.finders), only supports a subset of return types as detailed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.searchresulttypes)

In addition, I need to use the `SearchPage` return type as well, because there is metadata there that I need to make decisions on.

So I guess there are a couple of questions that come out of this:

- Is it possible to use `InnerField`s in derived query methods?  i.e. something like `SearchPage<PlayerEntity> findPlayerEntityByPlayerNumber_KeywordIn(List<String> playerNumbers, Pageable pageable);`
- Is it possible for a named query to return a `SearchPage`?  I think this might be possible with a custom Repository implementation, but if I could get either approach above to work that would be ideal.

Thanks for any help!!

spring-data-elasticsearch version: 4.0.3.RELEASE

spring-boot-starter-parent version: 2.3.3.RELEASE

elasticsearch version: 7.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question (*Is it possible for a named query to return a SearchPage?*): This is a bug that it does not work with `@Query` annotated methods. I fixed that yesterday for the *main*, *4.2.x*, *4.1.x* and *4.0.x* branches so it will work when the next service releases are out.

To answer the first one, I will need to do some research and tests before I can say anything about that - it would be great if it would work. I think I' can give more information later this weekend.

**Edit/Addition:**

The query derivation from the method name is based on the properties of the Java class and is done in the Spring Data base which knows nothing about these inner fields that only exist in Elasticsearch.

But you can use the following custom repository fragment:

```java
    public interface CustomPlayerRepository {
        SearchPage<PlayerEntity> findPlayerEntityByPlayerNumberKeywordIn(List<String> playerNumbers, Pageable pageable);
    }
```

```java
    public class CustomPlayerRepositoryImpl implements CustomPlayerRepository {
    
        private final ElasticsearchOperations operations;
    
        public CustomPlayerRepositoryImpl(ElasticsearchOperations operations) {
            this.operations = operations;
        }
    
        @Override
        public SearchPage<PlayerEntity> findPlayerEntityByPlayerNumberKeywordIn(
            List<String> playerNumbers, Pageable pageable) {
            var criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria("playerNumber.keyword").in(playerNumbers), pageable);
            var searchHits = operations.search(criteriaQuery, PlayerEntity.class);
            return SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, pageable);
        }
    }
```